# apply strsplit to multiple columns

Tags: r

I want to get rid of duplicates in strings that are separated by commas.

It works for a single column using:

```
df$column  <- sapply(strsplit(df$column, ",", fixed = TRUE), function(x) 
                                           paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))
```

When I try to use it on multiple columns I always get an "argument is a non-character" error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Could you provide some reproducable data for us to try your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to wrap with `as.character` if the column is `factor`

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$column), ",", fixed = TRUE),
      function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))
```

---

For applying to multiple columns loop through the columns of interest, apply the same function and update the output to the columns of interest

```
colsOfInterest <- c('column1', 'column2')
df[colsOfInterest] <- lapply(df[colsOfInterest], function(x) 
  sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), ",", fixed = TRUE),
       function(y) paste(unique(y), collapse=",")))
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I tried a similar approach but instead of naming the relevant columns with a vector, I tried to work with using their number in the dataframe. So insteadt of df[colsofInterest] I used df[c(4:9)] do you have an idea why that didn't work.

Comment: @Nico.444  Regarding the edited part of your comment, It should work as index or column names should both work assuming that they are referring to the same columns